# How do I track all interactions on my website with Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

This is often something I want to do when setting up a website. I don't know specifically what I'm looking to learn from analytics yet, so just track everything the user does. I also don't want to have to remember to call some analytics function every time I add a control.

This seemed like a very simple and common use case, but I was not able to turn up anything through research. There were a lot of javascript libraries for integrating with analytics, but they were mostly just api wrappers and didn't solve this problem.

Comment: this is the worst case scenario and not recommeded. You must not do it. Google analytics has the hit limit. You will see sample data if you just track everything ;) You must track all the import interaction only :)

Answer (score 0):

```
['click', 'change'].forEach(
    function( action ) {
        document.addEventListener(
            action,
            function( event ) {
                ga(
                    'send',
                    'event',
                    ( function( x ) {
                        return x['id'] || x['name'] || x['placeholder'] || x['textContent'] || 'unknown';
                    })( event.target ),
                    action,
                    document.URL );
            });
    });
```

The above code will give you a reasonable set of analytic data on all click and change events. This snippet can be placed alongside the snippet that you get from Google in your index.html file. The function that determines the category is set up to get more specific the more detailed the html element is. It assumes most buttons will have text, and most inputs will have a placeholder. Assigning a name or id to the element will override that and give you a more detailed category. If none of that is true, you'll see 'unknown' popping up in the analytics report with a URL, which should help in finding the item that needs more definition.